# Remove time part of a timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

How can I remove time part of a timestamp?

So for example turn `1310571061` to `1310565600` which is the plain date timestamp.

Comment: What is plain date in timestamp? You mean date+`00:00:00`?

Comment: @shef, yes I mean `Y-M-D 00:00:00`. No times calculated into the timestamp.

Comment: Also consider using DateTime object (see my answer below)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
strtotime(date("Y-m-d", 1310571061));
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: how about changing it to: `strtotime(date("y-m-d", time())` then  ?

Comment: @watcher, that will get the current date, yes.  That's not what he asked in his example.

Comment: Thanks brad, this works like a charm. You edited your answer, it was `strtotime(date("y-m-d"))` so it would only return today's timestamp, which is 1310565600 ;)

Comment: @Brad sorry, I was a bit confused about his comment to your answer.

Comment: @watcher, no worries, I'm confused too.  But I think it is cleared up now.

Comment: @Brad watcher's interpreting the requirement because David Weng said 'for example'. Good solution though +1

Comment: Reckon you should use capital `Y` so that four-digit dates are used...  or hope PHP isn't the new COBOL in 2100...

Answer (score 29):

In case you wanted a mathematical solution:

```
$time=1310571061;
echo floor($time/86400)*86400;
```

There are 86,400 seconds in 24 hours (which is the length of a *typical* day, but not all... see DST).  Since our timestamps are in UTC, this shouldn't be a problem.  You can divide that by the number of seconds in a day, drop the remainder, and multiply back out.

Comment: Cool. I tried `$time - ($time % 86400)` before asking the question gave incorrect results. Any ideas why?

Comment: @David, that works fine for me.  Perhaps casting $time to float first may help?

Comment: Careful! UTC has [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) making some days 8640**1** seconds long.

Answer (score 15):

Using a DateTime object can be helpful, and also can make the code more readable...

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp(1310571061);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d, H:i:s') . "\r\n";
$dt->setTime(0, 0, 0);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d, H:i:s');
```

Result...

> 2011-07-14, 03:31:01
>
> 2011-07-14, 00:00:00

The choice of whether to use raw timestamps or DateTime objects will depend a lot on the implementation needs, but generally speaking DateTime objects will go a long way towards reducing confusion and errors that can crop up especially around Timezone issues and Daylight Saving Time issues.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<?php
$ts = '1310571061';

echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $ts));
?>
```

Comment: `'Y-m-d'` is more conventional

Comment: @Yanick Rochon: Updated, that should satisfy! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$pubdate='2003-02-19T00:00:00.000-05:00';

   $da = strtotime($pubdate);
   echo $dat = date('Y-m-d', $da);
```

**The answer is like :"2003-02-19"**

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$date = strotime(date("y/m/d", $timestamp));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I usually do:

```
your_timestamp = pd.to_datetime(your_timestamp.strftime(format="%x"))
```

The function `strftime` will convert `your_timestamp` to a string without the time component. Then the function `pd.to_datetime` will convert it back to a `Timestamp` without the time component.